# MVYsideMenu for IOS without making root view controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, navigation-drawer

i am using MVYsideMenu inside a tabBar controller. but the issue is that when i declare sideMenuController as a root view controller so in other views tab bar is hide i.e. tab bar is not showing.
How can i achieve this without declaring it a root view controller.
Root view controller takes full screen.

```
[![UIStoryboard *storyboard = \[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil\];

homeMenuView *hMC = \[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeMenuView"\];
    // Create your main content view controller
    UITabBarController *tVC = \[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"\];
    // Initialize the MVYSideMenuController
    MVYSideMenuOptions *options = \[\[MVYSideMenuOptions alloc\] init\];
    options.bezelWidth = 0.0f;
    options.contentViewScale = 1.0f; // 1.0f to disable scale
    options.contentViewOpacity = 0.0f; // 0.0f to disable opacity
    MVYSideMenuController *sideMenuController = \[\[MVYSideMenuController alloc\] initWithMenuViewController:hMC contentViewController:tVC options:options\];
    \[\[\[UIApplication sharedApplication\] delegate\] window\].rootViewController = sideMenuController;
    \[\[\[\[UIApplication sharedApplication\] delegate\] window\] makeKeyAndVisible\];][1]][1]
```

Comment: Try use one of the tabs to init as `contentViewController` instead of `tVC`

Comment: its is also not working, then also new view controller takes full screen and tab bar hide.

Comment: Did you remove the `rootViewController` setting

Comment: @CodeForFun it it solved or not?